# Android camera takePicture() method execution time

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm new to developing apps in Android.

We are currently creating a robot using Android that accesses the camera for image processing.

My question is: How long will the takePicture() method in Camera class will finish executing from the time it take a picture to the time it stores the image data? Is it constant or you need to specify it?

I would appreciate it if you provide links with your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How long will the takePicture() method in Camera class will finish executing from the time it take a picture to the time it stores the image data?

It depends on the phone itself. What you should do is to save the image in an `AsyncTask` so you don't have to rely on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks. Are there android phones capable to capture image at 60 frames per second or more?

Comment: @Neigyl Noval: The video camera on the Android phones are not even capable of recording in higher than 24 FPS or whatever it is, so probably no.