# Android - Taking many camera pictures in short amount of time

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an Android application in mind that would require taking as many camera pictures as possible in say about 1 or 2 seconds.

I've thought of two possibilities:

1) Take various pictures for 2 seconds.

2) Record a video for 2 seconds and extract the frame images.

Which option do you suggest?

Do you think it would be possible to have at least 5 images per second with current hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest Method is to use the video function (multiple Frames per second).

But if you want to have hq pictures, it depends on your device:

This should help:

[Android camera takePicture() method execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722733/android-camera-takepicture-method-execution-time?rq=1)

http://www.workreloaded.com/2011/06/how-to-use-the-android-camera/

Answer (score 1):

i suggest the second. Because if the shutter speed of camera is low, the the app cant take multiple photos in one or two second. So better capture video and extract frames. but the problem is that video quality my be lower than image.

Answer (score 0):

Im quite sure extracting frames from video will be all blurry, at least when objects or the phone are moving. Just take a video and pause it to check.